# Automatically log folder changes

Tags: windows, automation, dropbox, monitoring

I have a dropbox folder on my windows desktop in which I frequently add photos to and rename them, it is a bit tedious to try and remember what photos I've recently added, so is there some way that I can easily have something that automatically monitors the dropbox folder then parses any changes such as file renemes, file deletions, file moves, and newly added files to a text file of some sort?

That would be cool thanks. PS This is not necessabilly a programming question as maybe there's a application on the web that can already do this - but whatever is deemed best for the specific request would give me more time to cap and crop the photos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Events page has a list of recent changes: https://www.dropbox.com/events

There is also an orange RSS button just above the list that gives you an RSS feed you can subscribe to.